# How to convert an IMethodSymbol to a MethodDeclarationSyntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, codefixprovider

Given an `IMethodSymbol` how can I create a `MethodDeclarationSyntax`?

Background:

For a code fix, I'm copying methods from one class which implements an interface into another which implements a different one.

As a result, I need to modify a few things on the copied method (parameters, namespaces, etc.).
I would like to modify the `IMethodSymbol`, convert the symbol into a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` and then add the symbol to the new class.

I have been able to do this by using the `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` property, but this doesn't work when the original class resides in a nuget package.

Using `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` (and some of my own code) I was able to do the following:

```
public static MethodDeclarationSyntax[] ToMethodDeclarationSyntax(this IMethodSymbol methodSymbol)
        {
            var namespaceValue = methodSymbol.ContainingNamespace.GetNameSpaceIdentifier();
            var syntaxReference = methodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences;
            var syntaxNodes = syntaxReference.Select(syntaxRef => syntaxRef.GetSyntax());
            var methodNodes = syntaxNodes.OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
            var methodExpression = methodSymbol.CreateExpressionSyntax();
            return methodNodes
                .Select(mds => mds
                    .WithExpressionBody(methodExpression)
                    .WithReturnType(SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(namespaceValue, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(mds.ReturnType.ToString())))
                    .WithParameterList(methodSymbol.GetFullyQualifiedParameterListSyntax())
                )
                .ToArray();
        }
```

Is there a way to generate a MethodDeclarationSyntax from an IMethodSymbol without using `DeclaringSyntaxReferences`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SyntaxGenerator.MethodDeclaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.editing.syntaxgenerator.methoddeclaration) which takes an IMethodSymbol. You probably don't want to be using DeclaringSyntaxReferences at all since that's only really useful in cases where your symbol came directly from source.